# Styling in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Having developed a few React-Native apps, I usually place all `Stylesheet` objects in a single `Theme.js` file that all components can require. I have found this really helpful and easier than each component having complicated Stylesheet variables.

In React, would a similar approach be recommended? Or am I able to use a conventional approach with a CSS file? There doesn't seem to be a definitive 'good' way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

There can't be neither a correct nor a incorrect answer. It is a matter of personal preferences, based on pros and cons of some approaches.

Below are some approaches beside "*complicated Stylesheet variables*".

## CSS-Modules

One possible solution might be the usage of [CSS-Modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules/blob/master/README.md). By using CSS-Modules, you could enjoy the pros of **real local scoping**, which fits very well with the module-based model of react components. By that you can define dependencies and keep the style and markup together.

The Github-repo of [CSS-Modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules/blob/master/README.md#why) lists some points, which summarize possible pros of this technique:

> **modular** and **reusable** CSS!
>
> - No more conflicts.
> - Explicit dependencies.
> - No global scope.

## Classic CSS

It is also possible to use common CSS. Either with a preprocessor or not.
With the usage of a naming convention, like [BEM](https://en.bem.info) suggests, it is possible to **imitiate local scoping** with namespaces. (`.cardmodule__`)

This looks like a good approach to support a **migration of an existing codebase to react**. But it has its downsides with defining dependencies.

---

I'm sure, that there are much more arguments. Maybe some could be added to the list bit by bit.